# start cell editor immediately on all cells

Tags: ag-grid

I am searching for a solution to how I can start an ag-grid table with only cell editors. That means I do not want to click into the row or cell to edit the data.

I have found almost a solution for me with this example in the doc:
[Full row editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-full-row-edit)

This is exactly what I am searching for. I can programmatically start editing immediately. The problem with that example is that `onCellValueChanged` is only fired after the keyboard click "enter" or click on the next row.
I would need a solution where `onCellValueChanged` is fired immediately after a cell changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ideas to accomplish this:

1. **Use "No Click Editing"**
   This is similar to having all cells contain an input box. It just takes 1 click to focus.
   https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#no-click-editing
2. **Custom cell renderer**
   Use a custom cell renderer to have input boxes in each cell. Then, you are always in edit mode. And you can control when the value is saved.
   https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Comment: "No Click Editing" is not the right solution for me. And "custom cell renderer" I think it would work, but I thought it is not allowed to have "editing components" in the renderer. But I think this is the only way, so I will program this in that way thank you